# При первом посещении сайта отображаются иероглифы

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3

При переходе на главную страницу сайта, иногда, вместо контента, отображается вот такая ["крякозябра"](http://prntscr.com/gdkjce) Из за чего это может быть?

CMS Joomla 3.7.5; PHP 7.0.22

Comment: Очевидно, у вас неверная кодировка.

Comment: @hedgehogues очевидно, неверная кодировка никак не может дать результат как на скриншоте

Comment: @hedgehogues браузер кодировку [видит](http://prntscr.com/gdkmbo)
Есть такая возможность, что иногда браузер не видит эту строку?

Comment: очень похоже на бинарный файл

Comment: Вообще без воспроизводимого примера это получается гадание и телепатия

Comment: @andreymal в этом и соль, что я даже не знаю, как это воспроизвести и писал в надежде, что кто то с этим уже сталкивался

Comment: @SerhijBanha причин может быть слишком много, чтобы ответить что-то конкретное. Может, так вообще и должно быть, кто знает)

Comment: Почему Вы не можете предоставить воспроизводимый пример?

Comment: переустановите джумлу из другого дистрибутива или иную версию и проблема исчезнет,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправилось обновлением до новой версии